# Getting all data from vectormaps

Tags: jquery, ajax

Alright, so I made this simple click system that will basically check if a country exists and then insert it into the database if it doesn't exist. Now I want to make a system that will just make ALL of those countries automatically. So basically.

1. I want to check what are the names of ALL maps inside the vectormaps
2. Each map name found should be sent as an AJAX request.

TL;DR: I want to send ALL Jquery Vector map names through the ajax without clicking or doing anything as such.
This is the plugin IM using http://jvectormap.com/

This is my current code

```
<script>
                $(function(){
                    $('#map').vectorMap({
                        map: 'world_mill',
                        onRegionClick: function(event,code) {
                            var map = $('#map').vectorMap('get', 'mapObject');
                            var name = map.getRegionName(code);

                            $.ajax({  
                                url:"handler.php",  
                                type:"POST",  
                                data:{function:"ajax_searchcountry", search:name},  
                                success:function(data){  
                                    alert(data);
                                }
                            });  
                        }
                    });


                });
            </script>
```

If it helps, this is how they process the data
http://jvectormap.com/maps/world/world/

Comment: ok, and what have you tried? where is the problem? or you are looking for someone to write this code for you?

Comment: Well the problem is I thought this would get all map names but it seems that it works only on the one I click on. I cannot find any solution on how to get ALL map names besides clicking on it.
EDIT: as you can see from my code, the only thing I was successful at was using Click event to do it but that goes only for the clicked map.